# ¿Por qué al utilizar pattern me valida algunas contraseñas?

Tags: ionic, regex

Tengo un campo `password` y un patrón, pero solo me valida algunas contraseñas.

Política del pattern:

- Mínimo 8 caracteres
- Una letra mayúscula
- Una letra minúscula
- Un carácter especial ( `!#$%&/()?¡_-`)

Utilizo el *framework* de *Ionic 2*.

La validación la estoy haciendo así:

```
public passRegex ="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" return this.formBuilder.group({
  correo: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.emailRegex)])],
  confirmarEmail: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.emailRegex)])],
  passwordRetry: this.formBuilder.group({
    clave: ['', [Validators.pattern(this.passRegex)]],
    passwordConfirmation: ['', [Validators.pattern(this.passRegex)]]
  },{validator:this.compararPass('clave','passwordConfirmation')})
},{validator:this.compararEmail('correo','confirmarEmail')});
```

Si coloco la cadena `Ejemploj#240518` funciona, pero si coloco `Pruebaenki#123456` no funciona.

> ionic info: 
> Your system information:
>
> Cordova CLI: **6.4.0** 
> Ionic Framework Version: **2.0.0-rc.2** 
> Ionic CLI Version: **2.1.8** 
> Ionic App Lib Version: **2.1.4** 
> Ionic App Scripts Version: **0.0.43** 
> ios-deploy version: **Not installed** 
> ios-sim version: **Not installed** 
> OS: **Linux 4.8** 
> Node Version: **v6.5.0** 
> Xcode version: **Not installed**

Comment: Los mas utilizados a la hora de crear una contraseña. !#$%&/()?¡_-

Comment: ok. Gracias voy a probar

Comment: Si funciona. Gracias por la ayuda. Podrías explicarme sobre esa expresión y cual era mi error?

Comment: Ok. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: He visto las ediciones de esta pregunta, la cual fue cerrada y las ediciones que se realizan para abrirla, creo que esta pregunta no debió ser cerrada!!! (⌐■_■)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La siguiente expresión regular coincide con un string de al menos 8 caracteres, con 1 letra minúscula, 1 mayúscula, y un símbolo entre `!#$%&/()?¡_-`. No considera letras con tilde, `ñ` u otros diacríticos como minúscula o mayúscula.

#### Regex:

```
(?=.*[-!#$%&/()?¡_])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}
```

#### Descripción:

Recordemos que con un [PatternValidator](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.1/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/validators.ts#L232) la expresión regular será comparada contra todo el string, por lo que ya está anclada a `^` (el principio) y `$` (el final del texto).

- `(?=.*[-!#$%&/()?¡_])` - Es una [aserción positiva](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions) (*[positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*) que coincide con la siguiente expresión sin consumir caracteres (y luego vuelve a la posición en la que estaba antes de intentarlo):

  - `.*` - 0 o más caracteres
  - `[-!#$%&/()?¡_]` - Es una [clase de caracteres](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-character-set) (*[character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)*) que coincide con 1 caracter (1 símbolo de los que están entre los corchetes).
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - [Aserción positiva](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) que coincide con cualquier caracter y luego 1 mayúscula. Recordemos que, como hasta ahora no se consumió ningún caracter, seguimos intentado desde el principio del texto.
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - [Aserción positiva](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) que coincide con cualquier caracter y luego 1 minúscula. Recordemos que, como hasta ahora no se consumió ningún caracter, seguimos intentado desde el principio del texto.
- `.{8,}` - El [punto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-dot) coincide con cualquier caracter (excepto `\n`). Con `{8,}` estamos [repitiendo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-quantifier-range) la estructura anterior entre 8 o más veces. Es decir, que coincide con 8 o más caracteres (cualesquiera), para comprobar el largo mínimo.

#### Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/VUXm3b/2